# Does vue router preloads every views and then displays it or does it do so by loading the view server only on request?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

By preload I mean , If the browser loads every views at once or do load the desired views form the server on request

Comment: Please let me know if you have any issues with my answer. If it helped consider marking it as correct as I put time and effort into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default they are indeed preloaded in the same javascript bundle file.

Anyways Vue Router has the lazy load feature so you can load your route components only when needed.

The syntax is as follows:

```js
const Foo = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "group-foo" */ './Foo.vue')
```

That would load the `Foo` component only when triggered by the route. Also the `webpackChunkName` comment is used to give a custom name to the js bundle file that will be loaded when lazy-loading that route (by default their names are just `[number].js`).

Check the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html#grouping-components-in-the-same-chunk) for more info about this last feature.